# How do I take the median of several columns in polars-rs?

Tags: pandas, rust

Say I have a `DataFrame` consisting of the following four `Series`:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use chrono::prelude::*;
use chrono::Duration;

fn main() {

    let series_one = Series::new(
        "a",
        (0..4).into_iter().map(|v| v as f64).collect::<Vec<_>>(),
    );
    let series_two = Series::new(
        "a",
        (4..8).into_iter().map(|v| v as f64).collect::<Vec<_>>(),
    );
    let series_three = Series::new(
        "a",
        (8..12).into_iter().map(|v| v as f64).collect::<Vec<_>>(),
    );

    let series_dates = Series::new(
        "date",
        (0..4)
            .into_iter()
            .map(|v| NaiveDate::default() + Duration::days(v))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
    );
```

and I join them as such:

```rust
    let df_one = DataFrame::new(vec![series_one, series_dates.clone()]).unwrap();
    let df_two = DataFrame::new(vec![series_two, series_dates.clone()]).unwrap();
    let df_three = DataFrame::new(vec![series_three, series_dates.clone()]).unwrap();
    let df = df_one
        .join(
            &df_two,
            ["date"],
            ["date"],
            JoinType::Outer,
            Some("1".into()),
        )
        .unwrap()
        .join(
            &df_three,
            ["date"],
            ["date"],
            JoinType::Outer,
            Some("2".into()),
        )
        .unwrap();
```

which produces the following `DataFrame`:

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬────────────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ date       ┆ a1  ┆ a2   │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ f64 ┆ date       ┆ f64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪════════════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 1970-01-01 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 8.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0 ┆ 1970-01-02 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 9.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0 ┆ 1970-01-03 ┆ 6.0 ┆ 10.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0 ┆ 1970-01-04 ┆ 7.0 ┆ 11.0 │
└─────┴────────────┴─────┴──────┘
```

How can I make a new `DataFrame` which contains a `date` column and a `a_median` column like so?:

```
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ a_median   ┆ date       ┆
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆
│ f64        ┆ date       ┆
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 4.0        ┆ 1970-01-01 ┆
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.0        ┆ 1970-01-02 ┆
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6.0        ┆ 1970-01-03 ┆
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7.0        ┆ 1970-01-04 ┆
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

I think this is best accomplished via `LazyFrame`s but I'm not sure how to get this exact result.

Comment: In your example, the a2 column is always the median. Is that realistic, or are you trying to find the median of a, a1, a2 regardless of the actual data? If the data could be different, you might consider unioning the dataframes rather than joining and then using group_by on the date and aggregate on the "a" column's mean

Comment: This is example data.  In my use case a1 will not always be the median value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results you're looking for, you can union the three DataFrames using the vstack method:

```
let mut unioned = df_one.vstack(&df_two).unwrap();
unioned = unioned.vstack(&df_three).unwrap();
```

Once you have a single DataFrame with all the records, you can group and aggregate them:

```
let aggregated = unioned.lazy()
                        .groupby(["date"])
                        .agg([
                            col("a").median().alias("a_median")
                         ])
                         .sort(
                            "date", 
                            SortOptions {
                                descending: false, 
                                nulls_last: true
                            }
                         )
                         .collect()
                         .unwrap();
```

Which gives the expected results:

```
    ┌────────────┬──────────┐
    │ date       ┆ a_median │
    │ ---        ┆ ---      │
    │ date       ┆ f64      │
    ╞════════════╪══════════╡
    │ 1970-01-01 ┆ 4.0      │
    ├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
    │ 1970-01-02 ┆ 5.0      │
    ├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
    │ 1970-01-03 ┆ 6.0      │
    ├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
    │ 1970-01-04 ┆ 7.0      │
    └────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: I take it that if I already have a dataframe with the columns separated, then I could use a similar method to first unionize the separate columns and then follow this method?